# How do I pass all parameters between cmdlets easily?

Tags: powershell, parameters

Using CmdletBinding, is there an easy way to regurgitate the exact parameters that a cmdlet was called with, so I can call another cmdlet with the exact same parameters?

I'm writing Powershell Cmdlets in Powershell. I'm using advanced functions. I have a cmdlet called Get-Environment, with several optional parameters like [string]EnvironmentName and [switch]Active. I have another cmdlet, called Get-Machine, with all of the same optional parameters; it calls Get-Environment. Originally, before I added the [switch]Active parameter, I simply called Get-Environment with all variables explicitly (see below).

I can't do the same thing now, because if I add "active" then it will be set. I don't want to have make a test in Get-Machine to see if Active is true and have two different versions of the Get-Environment call. I'd prefer to not have to trawl through the $PSBoundParameters hashtable and reconstruct the original strings, but that looks like the only feasible way forward (unless I'm missing something.)

Original code inside get-machine:

```
$environments = get-Environment -EnvironmentName $EnvironmentName
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh for Pete's sake. I found it. I was missing the big stupid easy thing. I'll leave this up for others, and in case someone has an even better answer.

https://ss64.com/ps/psboundparameters.html

> $PSBoundParameters can be used to call a subordinate function or cmdlet passing the same parameters - PowerShell will automatically splat the hash table's values instead of having to type each of the parameters: 
>   get-otherthing @PSBoundParameters